# RStudio only shows first 50 columns of a dataframe that consists of 505 variables (columns). The arrows don't work

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

My dataframe has 505 variables, but when I open it in R, it only shows the first 50 columns. The arrows for navigating to the following pages also don't work. I recently updated R to the newest version. Any ideas how to fix this?

The following also didn't work:

```
> utils::View(BothExams)
> options(width = 505)
> head(BothExams)
```

Comment: RStudio 2023.06? A known issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13220